# Adding basemaps in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, arcgis-online-basemaps

I have been using base maps in ArcMap 10.3.1 for the past week and all of a sudden today I cannot load anything.

I was using the National Geographic map with no problems (apart from occasional slowing down) but now when I even click on 'Add basemap' the whole application freezes i.e. I need to press Ctrl Alt Delete to exit ArcMAP.

I have gone to Customize->ArcMap Options and ensured that Hardware acceleration was enabled under data view. I've also cleared the display cache. The only licence settings I've altered is changing between basic and advances. My internet connection is fine as well (i.e. I'm on a work network, not at home).

I've read through the previous posts on adding base maps but I haven't seen any issue like this.

Comment: A bit old post but maybe worth a try: https://blogs.esri.com/esri/supportcenter/2013/04/01/having-issues-adding-arcgis-online-basemaps-to-arcmap/

Comment: Thanks Bera - I've just tried option 5 (adding the service through catalog) so now I can add the base map through Catalog, but not when I go to File->Add data->Add base map (or from the toolbar) - everything keeps freezing